# How to properly store/refresh third-party Oauth access token server-side

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

What is the proper way to store/refresh access tokens in my backend that I acquire when the user authorizes me to access a third-party app on their behalf?

I go through the Oauth server-side flow with Quickbooks Online (QBO) software and ask the user for permission to access their account (within certain scope). After the Oauth flow is complete, I have access, refresh tokens as well as a token id. How should I store these tokens in my database?

I could just save it in a database but then my refresh token might expire and I will have to take my user through another Oauth flow (which I want to avoid)

I could have a cron job that runs and refreshes all tokens when they are about to expire but this seems super hacky.

What is the proper way to store/refresh these tokens?

*p.s. Not sure if I'm phrasing my question correctly because I can't find any answers on SO yet and I'm sure people must have asked this before.*